# Apache JMeter WebDriver Sampler Failure : ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-5.0

I was using Selenium Webdriver 4.81 Sampler and with Apache-JMeter 5.5 using "java" as Script Language.
My code worked fine, until last week, I started facing the below error

```
ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:60730/devtools/browser/65875193-2def-446d-9a5b-07717e6ef06d
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:78) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:215) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:146) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:797) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:765) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:753) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

Here is my code snippet for the "Login" Sampler

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.Fileserver;

var driver=WDS.browser;

// Load Url
driver.get("https://sample.website/");
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1936, 1048));
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String title = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(title);
Assert.assertEquals("SampleTitle", title);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Login with Azure AD']")).click();
System.out.println("LoadUrl Successful");
WDS.log.info("LoadUrl Successful");
```

I understand I might need to add the below "dependency" and piece of code

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

Dependency to add:
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

I would really appreciate, if someone can aid me in resolving this query and help me add this dependency to the Apache-Jmeter Sampler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a proper place to put your `--remote-allow-origins=*` option for the chromedriver - it's [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/)

[image]

Going forward consider looking at:

1. JMeter consolue output ([stdout/strerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams))
2. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (you might want to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level)